# How do I write a 2D field of booleans to the console?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, 2d

I'm having trouble with this homework assignment. In the assignment we need to calculate the shortest path from A to B using BFS. However, first I want declare a 2D field of booleans in which 'true' is a passable tile and 'false' an impassable. Only the chars: .+?! are passable all others are not.

On the first line I declare the length and width of the plane, represented by integers h and b (ignore m). The length of the field is done correctly, the width however is not. The width should be the amount of chars equal to b.
This is what I have so far.

```
static void Main()
{
        int b, h;
        string m;

        string firstLine = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] declaration = firstLine.Split(' ');
        int.TryParse(declaration[0], out b);
        int.TryParse(declaration[1], out h);
        m = declaration[2];

        var input = new bool[h,b];
        for (int i = 0; i < h ; i++)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int j = 0; j < b ; j++)
            {
                foreach( char c in s)
                {

                    if (c.Equals('.') || c.Equals('!') || c.Equals('+') || c.Equals('?'))
                    {
                        input[i, j] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        input[i, j] = false;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

An input example with the desired output:
input:
6 6 L(ignore the L)
MMMMMM
M...?M
M....M
M+...M
M...!M
MMMMMM

desired output:
false false false false false false
false true true true true false
false true true true true false
false true true true true false
false true true true true false
false false false false false false

As of now I can still type in as many chars per line as I want and not the desired maximum b.

Also the console now writes System.Boolean[,]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You cannot just use Console.WriteLine on an array. You will have to look through input with x and y axis and use Console.Write(input[i][j]).
Or you can do Console.WriteLine inside the loop when you assign values of true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loops aren't working as intended! you basically have unnecessary nesting, the foreach loop is going through the whole string while the 2D array stays on the same index, also whenever an input is given the code goes to the right on the array,instead of going down.
to fix both of those problems I'd loop through the y values first AND remove the foreach loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < b ; y++)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int x = 0; x < h ; x++)
            {
                    char c = s[x];

                    if (c.Equals('.') || c.Equals('!') || c.Equals('+') || c.Equals('?'))
                    {
                        input[x, y] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        input[x, y] = false;
                    }

            } 
        }
```

**EDIT**: I suggest looping through the array to write out the value, the console will just type out the Object type if you feed it to it directly.